# I have a page that needs to automatically trigger the click event and pass parameters to him when entering

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});


  $(".divID").click(function (){
     var test = $(this).attr('value');
    });
```

How do I call the click event Parallel parameters

Comment: All your jQuery should be in your ready function. Also, that doesn't trigger a click event, it tests for one. Not that I would trigger a click Event, necessarily. I would just execute a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use trigger method of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".divID").click(function (){
     var test = $(this).attr('value');
   });
   $(".divID").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I want to ask if I can pass parameters at the same time?